# Should answer 7186727 to "What's in an Eclipse .classpath/.project file?" be treated as link-only answer?

Tags: discussion, flags, link-only-answers, specific-answer

Should [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7186727) answer to [What's in an Eclipse .classpath/.project file?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7186676) be treated as a link-only answer?

If so, then what is the proper flag for it? (VLQ not available; positively voted post)

If not, then why not?

Answer (score 4):

On first glance; its not a link only answer, as it is not just a "Look here" answer.

However, the OP clearly knows about these files, and is asking what to do with them. It looks like a link-only answer to me, as a markup-stripped version would clearly not answer the question.

Consider flagging as "Other", as a simple NAA flag would likely be declined by someone who didn't take the entire post into account during review (there are a *ton* of active flags; it happens).

Comment: "Other" was rejected, this question was a response to it ;)

Comment: @BleedingFingers Mistakes happen with those as well. If the message given wasn't descriptive enough, it could explain the decline.

Comment: Yes, of course. That's why I didn't mention it in the question and engaged the community.